# Opengeo Suite - What to do after a change of IP address?

Tags: boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I have an Opengeo Suite installed on a server. This server had a static IP address with which I could access the whole suite. 
Our internet provider changed the static IP and after this things are not working anymore. I can't load any map from online sources, neither Google layers or Bing layers are not showing up. 
I also get the following error in Geoexplorer:
This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. Please contact the site administrator. If you are the administrator of this site, please check the JavaScript console or check the following page for troubleshooting: http://g.co/mapsJSApiErrors

I didn't use a Google API Key until now.

So my question would be, what do I need to do in the case of an IP change? Do I need to update the IP address somewhere in the config files or anywhere else ?